# extract html using python beautiful soup is not working

Tags: javascript, python, html

I want to scrape information organized by states and cities

This is the Python script I'm using

```
import requests
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib3
import pyrebase
import numpy as np
import yagmail
import time
import math
import colorama
import sys
from algoliasearch import algoliasearch

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def getVendors():
    req = requests.Session()

    defaultlink = 'https://www.collierreporting.com/'

    driver.get(defaultlink)

    vendorsoup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html5lib");

    statecontainer = vendorsoup.find_all("li")

    for state in statecontainer:

        stateref = state.find('a')['href']
        statename = state.find('a').contents[0]

        driver.get(stateref)
        statesoup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html5lib");

        #GET CITIES
        citycontainer = statesoup.find_all("p")

        for city in citycontainer:
            cityref = city.find('a')['href']
            cityname = city.find('a')

            print( cityref, cityname)

        print(statename)

    print('Get vendors')

getVendors()
```

I was able to scrape the states in this html

```html
         <div class="content">

        <div class="column_1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/state/al">Alabama</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/state/ak">Alaska</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/state/az">Arizona</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/state/ak">Arkansas</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/state/ca">California</a></li>
              
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

but when I try to scrape the cities in this html, it does not work

```html
<div class="content">

<div class="column_1">
    <ul>
        <div style="margin-left: 20px;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Select a city to view dossiers.</span>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 7px; margin-top: 10px;"><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/city/alabaster-al">Alabaster</a></p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 7px; margin-top: 10px;"><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/city/alexander-city-al">Alexander City</a></p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 7px; margin-top: 10px;"><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/city/alexandria-al">Alexandria</a></p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 7px; margin-top: 10px;"><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/city/aliceville-al">Aliceville</a></p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 7px; margin-top: 10px;"><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/city/andalusia-al">Andalusia</a></p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 7px; margin-top: 10px;"><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/city/anniston-al">Anniston</a></p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 7px; margin-top: 10px;"><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/city/arab-al">Arab</a></p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 7px; margin-top: 10px;"><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/city/ardmore-al">Ardmore</a></p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 7px; margin-top: 10px;"><a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/city/ashford-al">Ashford</a></p>
 
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

this is the error I'm getting and can't figure why

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vendors.py", line 120, in getVendors()
  File "vendors.py", line 101, in getVendors cityref = city.find('a')['href']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I don't know why this is not working. I have tried multiple variations of getting the href and city names but all I got was the same "object is not subscriptable" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change city container to find all a tage and was able to the content like below

```
citycontainer = statesoup.find_all("a")

for city in citycontainer:

        cityref = city['href']
        cityname = city.contents[0]
```

I don't know why is different but it works